# Where to find a Carrot2 C# API?

Tags: carrot2

I'm been trying to use Carrot2 (clustering engine) in a C# project. They state that they offer a C# API, but the download links[1] are broken (404 - not found). Their support page[2] suggests to ask questions on SO, so I thought I'll post here.

Anyone with information on their official or any other non-official C# API for Carrot2?

[1] http://project.carrot2.org/download.html and http://download.carrot2.org/head/manual/index.html#section.integration.compiling-csharp-program-with-carrot2

[2] http://project.carrot2.org/contact.html

Comment: Ask them to rewrite their support page, to only use StackOverflow for *programming* questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the latest Carrot2 C# API:

http://get.carrot2.org/stable/3.10.3/

http://get.carrot2.org/stable/3.10.3/carrot2-csharp-api-3.10.3.zip

Comment: Thanks. Is there no download available for 3.10.3 (latest stable)? Does the API still require the server (DCS)?

Comment: The 3.10.3 build will be eventually available, they are built separately from the other binaries. The C# API is based in IKVM, so it does not required the DCS any more. However, as an alternative to the C#API, you can still use the DCS and access it from your C# code.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm wondering if IKVM use in the API (making it unmanaged I suppose) will pose a slight performance decrease compared to the the REST interface in DCS?

Comment: The IKVM-based port is indeed a bit slower than the native Java code. On the other hand, with the DCS you'd be paying the cost of data serialization / deserialization. Ultimately, it's a matter of testing with your specific data to see which is faster.

Comment: This is just to let you know that the Carrot2 3.10.3 C# API is available in http://get.carrot2.org/stable/3.10.3/.

Answer (score 0):

While the link in their 'User and Developer Manual' page is still broken, you can find a valid link at http://project.carrot2.org/download-csharp-api.html

The latest version which I just downloaded is 3.14.0